# Unreal Engine 4, Cry Engine ou Unity para networking

Tags: unity3d, unreal-engine

Preciso escolher entre estas 3 *engines* para poder desenvolver meu jogo em 3D. O principal ponto é que preciso conectar o cliente a um servidor escrito em Scala com o Akka através de TCP. Vi que todos eles tem soluções próprias, mas não gostaria de utilizá-las. Se não for possível, qual seria a melhor prática?

Comment: Olá. A sua pergunta está muito ampla, pois possíveis respostas devem discorrer sobre as características de comunicação TCP de cada uma das engines, sobre protocolos disponíveis no seu servidor em Scala, sobre vantagens e desvantagens de usar as soluções/servidores próprios de cada engine, etc. Talvez seja melhor você escolher uma das engines, fazer um techdemo pra avaliar suas possibilidades de comunicação, e ai então postar uma pergunta mais objetiva.

Comment: Se você está fazendo esse jogo sozinho vai ter um grande trabalho. CryEngine e Unreal Engine são engines muito grandes e complexas, Unity é um pouco menos. Mas é uma pergunta bastante subjetiva para o qual você deseja. Recomendo que dê uma olhada nas documentações de cada engine e avalie por si mesmo. Acredito que ninguém seja capaz de dar a resposta que você espera para essa pergunta.

Comment: Não estou fazendo sozinho, tem mais 2 programadores. O meu jogo precisa criar salas para jogadores de até 10 jogadores, mas todas controladas pelo servidor. É a partir de uma sala de espera que os jogadores são sincronizados pelo servidor e junta automaticamente em uma sala.